# How do I get the Parents and Grandparent and Great-Grandparent of an element?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, parent

SOLVED.
I am trying to get the grandparent, great-grandparent `ul` elements of a clicked on checkbox element in a tree structure, using jQuery's 'parents()' function.

I can get the parent `ul` element which has `class='accordion-heading'`, but I can't get it's parent and grandparent up to it's first ancestor of this branch, 
eg the first set of `ul` ancestor that has `class="accordion-heading"`, `data-target="#MMenu_DTID1"`and text = `Admin`, is not working.

The JQuery and Markup is:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; height: 80%;">
 <div class="panel-heading panel-head" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; width: 400px; height: 40px; background-color: gainsboro;">Security Permissions</div>
 <div class="panel-body" id="Permissions" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; width: 400px; height: 80%; background-color: ghostwhite;">
  <form action="/Security/Update" method="post">
   
   <div class="tree" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; height: 1200px; -ms-overflow-y: hidden;">
    <ul class="nav nav-list" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none;">
     <li>
      <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMenu_DTID1">
       <span class="checkbox MMTree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="MMTree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
       <input name="MM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
       Admin
      </span>
      <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="MMenu_DTID1" style="padding-left: 20px;">
       
       <li>
        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1">
         <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
         <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
         Users
        </span>
        <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="S_menu1" style="padding-left: 60px;">
         <li>
          <span class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu11">
           <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted11" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted11" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="2"></span>
           <input name="SM_IsPermitted11" type="hidden" value="false">
           new subby tst3
          </span>
          <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="S_menu11" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
           <li>
            <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1110">
             <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
             Read
            </span>
           </li>
           <li>
            <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1110">
             <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
             Create
            </span>
           </li>
           <li>
            <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1110">
             <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
             Update
            </span>
           </li>
           <li>
            <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1110">
             <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
             Delete
            </span>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>

       </li>
       <li>
        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1">
         <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red">
          <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1">
         </span>
         <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
         Contacts
        </span>
        <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="S_menu1" style="padding-left: 60px;">
         <li>
          <span class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu11">
           <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red">
               <input name="SM_IsPermitted11" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted11" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="2">
           </span>
           <input name="SM_IsPermitted11" type="hidden" value="false">
           BusinessContacts
          </span>
         </li>
        </ul>

       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

```js
 $(function ()
 {
  
  $(".subtree-checkbox").click(function (e)
  {
   e.stopPropagation();
            //this does get the immediate parent
   var parent = $(this).parent(".accordion-heading").attr("data-target");
   alert("checkbox parent = "+parent);


            //this does NOT work
   var parentEls = $(this).parents(".subtree-checkbox")

           //specifying 'ul' does work this now gets the id's (data targets of the accordion-classes)
            var parentEls = $(this).parents("ul")
    .map(function ()
    {
     return this.id;
    })
    .get()
    .join(", ");

   alert("PE " + parentEls);


  });
 });
```

Comment: What is `this` and `event.target` in your first code example? Your snippet is also broken.

Comment: hi. 'This' is the subtree-checkbox which was clicked on.
The other 3 are things I tried in the subtree-checkbox click event function.
i don't know what I'm supposed to do to get the snippet working fully. It seems to semi-work though.

Comment: I have updated this question's snippets with the Style and all other JS from the page I'm working on.

Comment: There's too much code here, have a read of [mcve].

Comment: Having said that, it *looks* like this code `$(this).parent(".accordion-heading")` is trying to find a span that's at the *same* level as the item being clicked.  You either want `$(this).siblings(".accordion-heading")` *or* you want `$(this).closest(".accordion-heading")` - but it's not clear from the vast amount of (mostly commented) code and the question exactly what you're trying to and and exactly what you're having difficulty with.

Comment: I have cleaned up the code, ..left the necesaary in. Hope that helps

Comment: My question is , how to find Parents and GrandParents and GreatGrandparents of the clicked on subtree-checkbox.

Comment: Problem resolved  thanks.
I have amended the script with the solution.

Comment: Please don't amend the original question with solutions. It obscures the original problem, making it unclear for future readers. This site is designed in a question and answer format, and you are allowed to answer your own question. It's not a discussion forum or anything else. So for the benefit of others (and for yourself, as people can then upvote you), can I suggest that you remove the solution from your question and restore it to its original state, and then write a separate Answer showing how you solved it, so people can compare and contrast. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, yes , will do.